# How to stop CLLocationManager Heading value change when iPhone roll little bit.

Tags: ios, core-location

My CLLocationManager is working fine. I can be noticed when the heading value changed.

However, I found the heading value are different when the iPhone roll even little bit angle.

I have set the

```
    locationManager.headingOrientation =  CLDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight
```

I have also set other properties:

```
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    orientation = getCLDeviceOrientation(by: UIDevice.current.orientation)
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.headingFilter = 0.1
    locationManager.headingOrientation = CLDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight
    locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    locationManager.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 1):

The `headingOrientation` property that you are setting is only used as reference point when you don't want the default: the top of the device in portrait mode represents due north (0 degrees)
Having set the reference, you will get changes in degrees for every [yaw movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaw_(rotation)).

You can see it documented here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620556-headingorientation